# Convert md5 hash to bigint in R

Tags: r, hash, md5, digest

I would like to know how to convert an md5 hash to a big integer so that I can apply the modulus operator to it.

I create the hash using the `digest` library:

```
h <- digest("luca", algo="md5", ascii=TRUE, raw=TRUE)
> h
[1] 18 0e 41 2e 42 db 5a 8c 45 3c 8a 81 c5 90 4e 5b
```

I would now like to convert `h` to a big integer and be able to apply the modulus operator (`%%`) to it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Rmpfr library<sup>1</sup>, the following works:

```
# Get a hex string of the MD5 hash:
h = digest("luca", algo="md5", ascii = TRUE, raw = FALSE)
result = mpfr(h, base = 16)
result
# 1 'mpfr' number of precision  128   bits
# [1] 31975486076668374554448903959384968795

result %% 1024
# 1 'mpfr' number of precision  128   bits
# [1] 603
```

---

<sup>1</sup> To install Rmpfr, one needs to install its dependency, the GNU mpfr library. See comments for further information.

Comment: It works fine! Thanks a lot!
For those having issuer intalling Rmpfr you need the library libmpfr-dev.

In a system like Ubuntu you can install it with:

sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev

and then install Rmpfr in R with:

install.packages("Rmpfr")

Comment: also, one can skip the paste step, by asking digest to produce strings:

h <- digest("luca", algo="md5", ascii=TRUE, raw=FALSE)

Comment: @lucacerone Cool. Since both are valuable comments, I’m going to put them directly into the answer for other users to see them easier.